# Is it possible to freeze task order in htop?

Tags: top, htop

In htop I would like to order processes by CPU utilization but the top processes bounce back and forth so it is difficult to view the details of each process. I would like to be able to sort in whatever preferred order then lock that order while each field continues to update.

Comment: I have the same issue. Unfortunately all the answers seem to suggest how to lower/stop the refresh rate, rather than freeze the task order while keeping a high refresh rate.

Answer (score 13):

A similar question was asked on superuser in February https://superuser.com/questions/1036978/how-pause-list-of-process-in-htop

The accepted answer is to use the `-d` option to change the delay of the refresh.

From the man page:

> -d --delay=DELAY
>
> Delay between updates, in tenths of seconds

e.g. `htop -d 100` to refresh every 10 seconds.

Judging by this bug report there is currently no way to pause htop completely. The suggestion is again to use the `-d` option. https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=821904

Comment: Inside the running ```top``` it is possible to press "```d```" key to change value of refresh rate (seconds), helpful if you ommit ```-d``` option at start

Answer (score 2):

Use `Z` key inside of htop. *Z: pause/resume process updates* (from htop help `F1`).

You will still be able to select and preview processes. Also memory and cpu usage will be updated as well

Comment: Looks like this feature was introduced around htop 3.0. At least there's a change to it in the changelog at 3.0.3, and it doesn't seem to be present in the latest 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> to follow a process in htop.

Comment: True, but following a process is different from "freezing a task order", right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the cursor keys or click with the mouse to select a process line.
It will freeze the order of the tasks but keeps refreshing.

To unfreeze, press Tab.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but, press <kbd>F2</kbd> which will open *Setup* menu, on the first tab press <kbd>Arrow down</kbd> to get to *Display Options*, then left to go to the check boxes, go down now and check *Update process names on every refresh* and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to save. Now restart `htop` and nothing will move around.